# What are projective spaces?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I am trying to understand Projective Spaces, but I have to be honest is not so easy for me. I premise that I am not a mathematics student and I have not studied anything about topology and only a very little of differential geometry.

Unfortunately, I have to learn about projective spaces even if I don't have any background, so after spending much time trying to understand it, I am here asking for help.

I have found some video lectures and some explanations about this topic, but I have also to understand terms like rank 1 orthonormal projectors and chordal distance, which I really can't understand what they are.

What I would like to ask is: **Does it exist some reference which explains these arguments easily or can someone give me a simple explanation of these concepts?**

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you need to learn about projective spaces for?

Comment: I am studying consensus protocol, but in my readings it ia assumed that the concept of projective space is known. I am sorry if I say something that probably is not vey correct, but I really know nothing about topology.

Comment: What is the connection between consensus protocols and projective spaces?

Comment: It really depends on what exactly you need. As with any topic in mathematics (or life), one can go arbitrarily deep into the subject. The essential idea of projective space is to add points "at infinity", so annoying case distinctions like '2 lines either intersect or are parallel" are avoided. After adding points at infinity, parallel lines are just those that intersect "at infinity". Algebraically, one can then coordinize the space by introducing homogeneous coordinates, etc etc.

Comment: In order to properly understand what projective spaces are you really need to learn some basic topology, at the very least the fact the definition of a topological space. Incidentally, the answer will depend on whether you are working with real or complex projective spaces. (Or, maybe, you are working with projective spaces over finite fields?)

Comment: @MoisheKohan I‘m not sure if one actually needs to do that (but of course it depends on the context of the OP), one can learn much of classical projective geometry (i.e. studying classical results related to the double ratio, etc.) without knowing about topology. At least there were several courses in my old university that did this. But of course knowing topology doesn‘t hurt but will certainly help.

Comment: @QiZhu: Could be. But, I am guessing, OP needs the modern notion of a projective space (this is the context where "chordal  distance" will make sense).

Comment: sorry for the late reply to the comments, I was trying to get more informations on the subjects. Reading more about it, it seems it was referring to something called Grassmann manifold, and it is mentioned that each point of it is represented by an orthonormal projector $\pi=y^Ty$. But I am still really confused sorry. I post here a paper in which it is talked about it: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.4275.pdf

Comment: grassmanians are a bit different (actually more general) than projective space. You can start by think of them as the "set" of k dimensional subspaces of an n dimensional vector space $V$. one can start to describe these objects in a variety of ways. The topology comes roughly as you expect it (two hyperplanes for example are close if you only move one slightly to obtain the other.) You can start specifying certain points in the grassmanian by imposing linear conditions that result in a k-dimensional subspace

Comment: the exposition in the paper is not bad, and it is in fact only a specific example treated throughout useful for computation.